# Primefaces nested dataTable render problems

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using Primefaces with JSF2.0.
I have a nested dataTable which I want to be rendered only if some boolean flag(safeToLoadDataTable) is true, but this doesn't happen and when I open the page record.columnList throws NullPointerException because obviously it isn't yet initialized. I fill those lists after a search button from the same page it's pressed.

My Code:

```
<p:panel rendered="#{enastrSearch.safeToLoadDataTable}">
                <p:dataTable id="tableData" var="record" value="#{enastrSearch.recordsList}" >
                    <p:column>
                        <p:dataTable var="column" value="#{record.columnList}">
                            <p:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    Name
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{column.columnName}" />
                            </p:column>

                            <p:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    Value
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{column.columnValue}" />
                            </p:column>
                        </p:dataTable>
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
            </p:panel>
```

Why doesn't the rendered attribute work? And I was also wondering if using nested dataTable is OK.
Thank you!

UPDATE:

My flag looks like this:

```
private boolean safeToLoadDataTable;

    public boolean isSafeToLoadDataTable() {
        if(recordsList!=null && !recordsList.isEmpty()){
            safeToLoadDataTable = true;
        }else{
            safeToLoadDataTable = false;
        }


        return safeToLoadDataTable;
    }
```

Anyway I've tried even with return false and still the panel is rendered.

Comment: How does your managedbean look like?

Comment: So, the panel is still shown when you use `<p:panel rendered="false">`? What PF version are you using?

Comment: Did you try `<p:panel rendered="false">`?

Comment: No I didn't tried <p:panel rendered="false">... I was talking about the isSafeToLoadDataTable method return.

Comment: I would also have another question: How to show a list members only on a single row? Because if I use dataTable and column, automatically makes the rows, if I use the p:row it doesn't work...

Comment: It's hard to help you out if you don't try anything nor give any feedback. Once again: is it still shown when you use `<p:panel rendered="false">`? Yes or No? What PF version are you using? 2.1? 2.2? 2.2.1? 3.0 M1? etc.

Comment: I'm using PF 2.2.1. When I use <p:panel rendered="false"> it's not shown.

Comment: Can you show more (all) of you managedbean-code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *when I open the page record.columnList throws NullPointerException because obviously it isn't yet initialized*

You should not do anything else in `getColumnList()` than just returning the list property. The getter should look like exactly this:

```java
public List<Column> getColumnList() {
    return columnList;
}
```

It should not contain any other code. Any initialization of this property should be done in the bean's (post)constructor or action(listener) methods.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, I'd suggest to just use `empty` keyword in EL instead of that clumsy boolean getter.

```html
<p:panel rendered="#{not empty enastrSearch.recordsList}">
```

Comment: I did not knew there is an empty EL keyword... Thank you BalusC! I wasn't trying to be ambiguous, it's just that I'm rather new to JSF, Spring and I'm trying to do a lot of things at once and sometimes I'm a bit...carried away.